# loadmask in sencha touch2

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want apply load-mask in view page. while launching the application, some view pages are taking time to load data later it will display, so if its taking time to load in that time i want show load-mask to users with some messages like "loading....". from some sample i have applied load-mask, but it is shows that message every time whenever i hit that page. this is bad way because here setting time. **i need apply load-mask like this if don't have data it should show the load-mask to the user, until page getting the data. please any one help me. how to achieve this one**

**My code is here:** *at controller level i am taking the id of load-mask and setting the property as shown below code*

```
onCompanyPageLoad: function () {
    var loader = Ext.getCmp('mask');        
    loader.setMessage("Loading...");
    loader.setIndicator(true);
    loader.setTransparent(false);      
    loader.show();        
    setTimeout(function () {            
        loader.hide();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer of **user978790** is formal way to show and hide a loading mask in Sencha Touch 2.

If you can't make it work, it's very likely that you're doing something like:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'your custom loadmask'});
... then do something here
Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
```

Note that Javascript is asynchronous, so it does NOT make sure that the code lines are run in above order. Then there is a possibily that Sencha Touch initializes your loading mask and destroys it right then. In order to use loading mask correctly:

1. Initialize a loading mask as above.
2. Put the `Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);` in ***special*** functions which are ensured to be launched after loading mask initialization, eg. event handler, or success function of your JSONP/AJAX request.

Answer (score 7):

I do it the following way:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'your custom loadmask'});
```

Then you can use

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
```

To stop showing a loading mask
This also works on components if you only want to show a mask on part of a view

Comment: Can you post the exact code you've tried? This should work in every case it puts a load mask on the entire viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all this.I have nice idea how to use loader.First on main page html just add loader

```
<div id="loader"></div>//add id#loader with background loading image
```

after your page loads just add on contoller `Ext.get('loader').destroy();`//when you page full load then it will load your loading div

Comment: ..i have define id as loader in view page. at controller i have CompanyProfileViewInitialize function at the bottom this function i have applied this code Ext.get('loader').destroy();. this function get the data and initialize page.. but here i am not able to c d load-mask. anything wrong in my way of doing..